# SASS - change background based on secondary class

Tags: css, sass

I have the following SASS class:

```
.riskBlock {
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  .Critical {
    background-color: #7f2121;
  }
  .high {
    background-color: #ff0000;
  }
  .medium {
    background-color: #ff9900;
  }
}
```

My goal is to have an HTML tag like this:

and show the background based on the secondary class, `critical`. Currently - only the background I set in the main class (aka `riskBlock`) is shown.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Nested selectors in SASS creates [ancestor selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) in CSS, something like `.riskblock .Critical`. What you want is to select elements that have both classes. You can do this in SASS using the [parent selector](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector):

```
.riskBlock {
  /** ... */
  &.Critical {
    background-color: #7f2121;
  }
  &.high {
    background-color: #ff0000;
  }
  &.medium {
    background-color: #ff9900;
  }
}
```

This yields the following result:

```css
.riskBlock.Critical {
    background-color: #7f2121;
}
.riskBlock.high {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
.riskBlock.medium {
    background-color: #ff9900;
}
```